# Make python3 subpackage module available for import in main package namespace

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I have the following dir structure

```
mainpackage
├── __init__.py
└── subpackage
    ├── __init__.py
    └── module.py
```

Module.py contains

```
def test():
    print("test called")
```

Using python3 I am looking to make the module.py module available for import  in the mainpackage namespace. So far my mainpackage __init__.py file looks like this

```
from .subpackage import module
```

I would like to be able to call

```
import mainpackage.module
```

but this throws

```
ImportError: No module named 'mainpackage.module'
```

Just for clarity, I am **NOT** looking to import the test function into the mainpackage namespace - I want the entire module. Is this possible ? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot make a module of a subpackage available in the namespace of the mainpackage like you tried:

```
import mainpackage.module
```

looks for a module in the subdirectory of `mainpackage` and not in any other (deeper) subdirectories.

What you tried in the `mainpackage\__init.py__` is correct. Your

```
from .subpackage import module
```

will make the module availabe on `mainpackage` level. If you type in an IPython console

```
import mainpackage
mainpackage.module
```

will give the following output

```
<module 'mainpackage.subpackage.module' from 'your\path\mainpackage\subpackage\module.py'>
```

but `import mainpackage.module` still won't work. If you now want to use `module` as an instance you have to use

```
from mainpackage import module
```

which will allow you to use your function like this

```
module.test
```

Answer (score 0):

Import it this way `from mainpackage.subpackage import module` and you don't need `from .subpackage import module` in the init file

Comment: I am aware you can do that but it doesnt make it available in the mainpackage namespace. I want to call import mainpackage.module

Comment: do you have another file in the mainpackage which uses subpackage?

Comment: Not at the moment no

Comment: just call `import mainpackage.subpackage.module` because it doesn't make any difference what is imported in the mainpackage init file python will still throw the error. Basically you want to import the import but that's doesn't work